# AWS DynamoDB with provisiond write throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We host a large website on AWS. We anticipate a large and undetermined amount of traffic that will generate many writes. Is it possible to use DynamoDB with provisioned write throughput?

If I am running RDS. Does RDS allows provisioned IOPS?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use DynamoDB with provisioned write throughput?

That's an extremely vague and open-ended question. [Yes it is possible](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughputIntro.html) to provision throughput with DynamoDB.

> Does RDS allows provisioned IOPS?

[Yes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html#USER_PIOPS). I feel like it would have taken less time to search for the answer to that than it did for you to ask the question.